# Error when loading mySettings [Visual basics 2010]

Tags: vb.net

i get this error when i load my setting
it only happens when i take out the exe from my debug

> See the end of this message for details on invoking 
>   just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>   ************* Exception Text **************
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section userSettings. (C:\Users\Zack\AppData\Local\Optimum_Products\Optimum_Command_Generator_StrongName_tvel5evqwafxml0wgf04wxshpjpy2wyr\1.0.0.0\user.config line 3)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **app.config** or **Settings.resx** file? If you are using app.config file then you'll need to copy "Application Name".config file with your executable.